# Programs for easing (tape) backups?

Tags: open-source, backup, debian, unix

I already asked on the unix stack exchange but was unaware of this specific stack exchange. So I'll ask here instead.

I was thinking about making a simple suite of scripts that would all be used in one larger script to do all the basics you might need to read/write to tape effectively. This would use already established programs (probably STAR and encfs) so all the script would do is ease the use of tape for the end user.

I was wondering though if something has already been created like this? I know things like bacula exist, but at a cursory glance they don't look like what I am searching for. Some may very well not work on my specific tape drive, they do far more than I need them to do, and I've heard they have issues with portability and use with older backups. Not to mention there are quite a few that are proprietary, only partially open source (you have to "sign up" to get certain features, for example) and/or only work on Windows.

I am a complete newbie in this arena. I have searched rather extensively and turned up nothing, nor did my previous post provide any answers either.

Required elements:

- Works on Debian Linux
- **Cannot** have a hard dependency on SystemD
- Can do all the basics you might need to use a tape to make backups

Preferred elements (not required, simply preferred):

- Works on FreeBSD
- Has a small code-base
- It's standard package should not come bundled with SystemD, either

Does such a beast exist? Please do not suggest LTFS, as I'll be working with LTO-4 tapes primarily and thus cannot utilize it.

Obviously I could just use STAR or TAR but I am specifically looking for a program that works something like `program -write folder -drive /dev/xxx`. Just something incredibly easy and stupid-resistant. Obviously I could just use something like bacula, but for the reasons above I'd prefer not to.